# Mark standard library method as `Obsolete` or otherwise "hiding" it

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, f#

[`String.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) optionally takes a `StringComparison` enum (e.g. `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`). I keep forgetting to specify `IgnoreCase`, so I want to mark that method as `[Obsolete]` so I see it in `Warnings` so I remember to specify the kind of `StringComparison`.

I'm open to other solutions too, like doing something to "hide" that method and prevent it from being called. The ideal solution doesn't involve Roslyn analyzers though, as I'm using F#.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490481) is interesting, but obviously not ideal.

Comment: I usually wrap things like that in my own utility library. As for analyzers, I simply write a few unit tests that go through my source and e.g. do a text search for things I don't want to creep in. So I don't get notified at compile time, but getting it at build time is not bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Extension Method. Just put it somewhere that's available to all your code, and declare it directly in the System namespace. (I'm not fluent in F#, but this should work.)

```
namespace System

type String with
  member CaselessContains(str) = String.Contains(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ionide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ionide.Ionide-fsharp) for [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) supports [analyzers](https://ionide.io/Libraries/fsanalyzers.html). You'd have to write one for the methods you want to disallow.